# How can I solve the error message I am receiving in my below code in my policy documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the below error when i run terraform apply :
Invalid template interpolation value
var.oidc_condition_statement is list of string with 2 elements Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "Orchestration_role"{
    name = var.orchestration_role_name

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
           "Principal":{
               "Federated":"arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_oidc_account}:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
           },
           "Condition":{
               "ForAnyValue:StringLike":{
                   "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "${var.oidc_condition_statement}"
               }
           }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

variable.tf

variable "oidc_condition_statement"{
    type = list(string)
}

tfvars

oidc_condition_statement          = ["repo:organization/terraform-aws-githubaction:ref:refs/heads/staging","repo:organization/terraform-aws-githubaction:pull_request"]
```

Comment: What is the full error message? Which line does it occur?

Comment: Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on iam_role.tf line 17, in resource "aws_iam_role" "Orchestration_role":  17:                      "${var.oidc_condition_statement}"

Comment: Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   
│    4:     assume_role_policy = <<EOF
│    5: {         },
│   14:            "Condition":{
│   15:                "ForAnyValue:StringLike":{
│   16:                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub":[
│   17:                      "${var.oidc_condition_statement}"
│   18:                    ]
│   19:     
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.oidc_condition_statement is list of string with 2 elements
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `jsonencode`:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "Orchestration_role"{
    name = var.orchestration_role_name

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
           "Principal":{
               "Federated":"arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_oidc_account}:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
           },
           "Condition":{
               "ForAnyValue:StringLike":{
                   "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": ${jsonencode(var.oidc_condition_statement)}
               }
           }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: if you don't mind,can you please explain to me why jsonencode was used

Comment: @bibi The function will take your list of strings in TF, and correctly convert it to list of strings in json format, which is needed for IAM policies.